# Google Meet / WebRTC calls drop in Firefox when removing docker networks on Linux

Tags: docker, firefox

I am working on a Linux laptop, I use docker containers for development and I run them on my local docker engine (i.e. just `docker compose up -d`).

I've noticed that Google Meet calls drop if I do `docker compose down` when on a video call. I have a very typical docker compose setup (two containers, one network). The call on the host drops almost every time for the audio/video, but certainly always kills the screen sharing.

This happens on both Firefox 121 and Firefox Aurora (122.0b5), but does NOT happen on Chrome or Chromium.

#### **Why are my calls being dropped?**

I suspected that NetworkManager was reacting to the docker network changes, so I made sure that the docker related interfaces are always "unmanaged" by adding to my NM config:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker*;interface-name:veth*;interface-name:br-*
```

... but the problem persists.

I am on Debian 12, Linux 6.5, Docker 24.

Comment: And how is docker relevant? What is it that is dockerized? Are you running Debian dockerized? Firefox dockerized on a baremetal Debian install? Something else? If you clarify, that will help others benefit from your helpful Q&A (and thanks for doing things like this, they're very welcome!)

Comment: @terdon having a network interface (the br-*) appear and disappear is confusing Firefox, which runs in the same host as the Docker engine. This is a typical setup for a developer working with anything docker on a Linux workstation/desktop. Do you think it's best to remove the docker tag? In practice I think this is unlikely to happen in scenarios without docker involved. I will try to clarify the setup anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in how Chrome and Firefox WebRTC stacks use Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE).

Both browsers maintain a list of "ICE candidates" for communication. Chrome only uses candidates from the default network interface (the one for the default route, i.e. your wlan or eth adapter interface). In contrast, Firefox considers all interfaces by default, including the `br-*` and `veth*` generated by docker.

To avoid WebRTC issues in Firefox, you can configure it to ignore interfaces that are not the default one. Through the special `about:config` URL, **just set `media.peerconnection.ice.default_address_only` to `true`.**

The documentation is scarce, but from [this Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Media/WebRTC/Privacy) we see the different ICE settings that affect candidate generation, in particular:

> `media.peerconnection.ice.default_address_only` - `boolean` (default
> `false`) -- limit ICE candidates to the default interface only.
>
> - The default interface used for general routing is identified and only that address is used for candidate generation
>   ...

NOTE: This setting can have negative impact combined with VPNs.